# Search SQL query where this is true

Tags: php, sql, search

I have a search query that works great, but I need it to only show results where `visible = true`. That's what needs to be added to the query, I just don't know how to do it correctly. Here's the query.

> $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT
>   id,name,company,town FROM people
>   WHERE name LIKE '%$mysearchString%' OR
>   company LIKE '%$mysearchString%' OR
>   town LIKE '%$mysearchString%' ORDER BY
>   name DESC LIMIT 100");

The $mysearchString var is just a sanitized `$_GET['s']`.

Comment: `visible` is a column in the `people` table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT id,name,company,town 
FROM people WHERE 
(name LIKE '%$mysearchString%' 
OR company LIKE '%$mysearchString%' 
OR town LIKE '%$mysearchString%')
 AND visible = true
ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Thanks, Tyler! Worked a treat.

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT id,name,company,town FROM people WHERE (name LIKE '%$mysearchString%' OR company LIKE '%$mysearchString%' OR town LIKE '%$mysearchString%') AND visible = true ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT 100");
```